# different environments in CakePHP?

Tags: development-environment, cakephp-2.0, production-environment

I wanna have many environments in my CakePHP application,

and have a core.php file for each environment, i.e.,

core-production.php and core-development.php. How to manage it?

Comment: What will the difference be between the production and development files? I just manage them from the same core.php.

Comment: @Wylie It will automate the selection of configuration values, and thus less chances of errors and less monotonous labor.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to load different configurations for each location. The best way to manage this is to establish [custom configurations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class) based on the location of the server.

So to do this, you can create a custom.php configuration that checks the server name.

```
$domain = strtolower(@$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
switch (true) {
  default:
  case 'production.domain.com' == $domain:
    Configure::write('MyDomain.environment', 'production');
    break;

  case 'staging.domain.com' == $domain:
    Configure::write('MyDomain.environment', 'staging');
    break;

  case 'local.domain.com' == $domain:
  case 'mybox.com' == $domain:
    Configure::write('MyDomain.environment', 'local');
    break;
}
```

Now, in the core, you can configure the settings based on your environment:

```
switch (Configure::read('MyDomain.environment')) {
  default: // for security; wouldn't want any confusion revealing sensitive information
    case 'production':
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    break;

  case 'staging':
  case 'local':
    Configure::write('debug', 2);
    break;
}
```

Now you can configure everything anywhere using `Configure::write('MyDomain.environment', x)` without having to modify the way the CakePHP core reads the files.

Happy coding!

Comment: That is the best way to switch on strings I've ever seen.